# (When) Does the Xamarin.iOS garbage collector stop the whole application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, garbage-collection

The [Xamarin Cross-Platform Performance Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/memory_perf_best_practices/#sgen) states:

> When SGen starts a garbage collection, it will stop the application’s threads while it reclaims memory.

I'm wondering about a few details:

- I very much assume this applies to Xamarin.iOS? Is this correct?
- Does this apply to the whole application? That is, also the unmanaged side?

  - Is the native ui thread stopped as well?
  - Are unmanaged threads stopped as well? E.g. threads created by a native library which is wrapped via P/Invoke?
- Do all collections (minor and major) stop the threads? Or does this only apply to major collections?
- Just in case: Has the behaviour changed in the last year?

  - Reason for this last question: Alongside the [current stable release of Xamarin iOS](https://releases.xamarin.com/category/stable/), we are using [Cycle 6 Service Release 4](https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-cycle-6-service-release-4/) for bugfixes for an older product. On both toolchain versions, we are developing unified applications using the *SGen* garbage collector.

Answer (score 2):

The standard caveat applies that you should profile to see how this plays out in your case, but here are some answers:

1. This certainly applies to Xamarin.iOS.
2. Yes, this will block the UI thread.
3. I would guess that 'pure unmanaged' background threads, ie launched from native libraries and not referring to any managed code, wouldn't be blocked, but that's a guess.
4. Minor collections will also block, but typically for a much shorter time.

And lastly, yes, this has recently changed significantly with the addition of [concurrent garbage collection](http://www.mono-project.com/news/2017/05/17/concurrent-gc-news/):

> Traditionally, when Mono’s memory manager determined that it should
>   perform a garbage collection, the collector had to pause all Mono
>   running threads, perform the garbage collection, and once it was done,
>   it resumed the execution of those threads.
>
> With concurrent garbage collection, we are able to perform collections
>   on the old generation (what we call major collections) mostly
>   concurrently with your application - it happens at the same time as
>   your program is running. When the major collection is completed, the
>   collector only needs to pause the Mono threads for a very brief period
>   of time at the end.

Concurrent GC is available as a build option in the current stable version of Xamarin (see [link](http://www.mono-project.com/news/2017/05/17/concurrent-gc-news/) for details).